How To Comine Mono and Flux To Apply Custom logic
I have below response data available:
Mono<Object1> result1 =  //some Spring CRUD repo call 

Mono<Object2> result2 =  //some Spring CRUD repo call 

Flux<Object2> result3 =  //some Spring CRUD repo call 

I need to process the above objects and create a new object in such a way that the resulting object depends on all three objects.
Out of the above three, results 2 and results 3 need to be processed simultaneously and the result 1 needs to be processed independently (independent method )
Results 2 and Results 3 will be processed in such a way that a single method needs to have all the objects (elements in the stream ) available to apply the logic
Like below
public void processResult2AndResult3(single Mono and Flux (all elements) should be available here at one go ){

  //code here 
}

I searched for the solution and I have got below code :
Mono<String> mono1 = Mono.just("x");
Flux<String> flux1 = Flux.just("{1}", "{2}", "{3}", "{4}");
mono1.flatMapMany(m -> flux1.map(x -> Tuples.of(x, m))).subscribe(System.out::println);

But here output will come in tuples like below -
[{1},x]
[{2},x]
[{3},x]
[{4},x]

Can anybody let me know please how can we get the elements in  Mono and Flux in such a way that the method processResult2AndResult3 get input parameters as expected ? Meaning a single Mono and all Flux elements at one go ?
And not like -
[{1},x]
[{2},x]
[{3},x]
[{4},x]


You have to collect all the elements from the Flux into a list to access them at once. That could be .collectList() method.
The code could be just:
Mono<List<Object3>> result3list = result3.collectList();
result2.zip(result3list)
   .map(pair -> {
      // 
      // process the pair tuple that contains both results
      // pair is a Tuple2<Object2, List<Object3>>
   });

